libmnl library arm cross-compile failed
I try to build command
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-static=no --prefix="/arm/libmnl-1.0.5/build"
make

I want to use the lib/libmnl.a generated in the build directory by the compile command above.
However, if you flag it via LIBMNL_PATH = ./lib/arm/libmnl.a and try to build it, you get the following error
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: ./lib/arm/libmnl.a: error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

You have specified the arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib command to libmnl.a, but this does not solve the problem.
Can you give me a guide to cross-compile this library to ARM 32bit?
If you successfully cross-compile the libmnl library to ARM, you should be able to flag libmnl.a for use.
